# Different div background image for Firefox and IE

Tags: css, clip-path

I made a `clip-path` and use a `.gif` in the background to make it look amazing. But, I encountered a problem: Firefox and IE don't support `clip-path`. Instead, they just show the background image in a very ugly matter. Is there any way I can put a different background image for Firefox and IE users?

CSS:

```
.thisdiv {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background-image: url("image.gif");
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(3% 3%, 43% 3%, 54% 4%, 61% 5%, 67% 7%, 74% 10%, 79% 13%, 84% 17%, 88% 22%, 91% 27%, 94% 34%, 96% 41%, 97% 48%, 97% 56%, 95% 64%, 93% 71%, 90% 76%, 86% 81%, 82% 85%, 77% 89%, 60% 60%, 78% 50%, 28% 22%, 28% 78%, 47% 67%, 63% 94%, 56% 96%, 48% 97%, 3% 97%);
  clip-path: polygon(3% 3%, 43% 3%, 54% 4%, 61% 5%, 67% 7%, 74% 10%, 79% 13%, 84% 17%, 88% 22%, 91% 27%, 94% 34%, 96% 41%, 97% 48%, 97% 56%, 95% 64%, 93% 71%, 90% 76%, 86% 81%, 82% 85%, 77% 89%, 60% 60%, 78% 50%, 28% 22%, 28% 78%, 47% 67%, 63% 94%, 56% 96%, 48% 97%, 3% 97%);
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so this is what I did (for those interested). I used 'css-hacks':

```
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #div2{
        display: block;
    }
    #div1 {
        display: none;
    }
}

@supports (-ms-accelerator:true) {
     #div2{
        display: block;
    }
    #div1 {
        display: none;
    }
}

_:-ms-lang(x) {
       #div2 {
        display: block;
    }
    #div1 {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Using this I hide the `<div>` with the clip-path for the browsers that don't support it, and show them another `<div>`  instead. It's not the prettiest way to do it, but it doesn't require JS.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, clip-path isn't too widely support just [yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

So, your best option would be to include a [polyfill](https://github.com/AlfonsoFilho/ClipPath) in your site

Unfortunately, that aspect of your site will be reliant on JS and so wont work if the client has it turned off

Comment: that's too bad. Isn't there a workaround? Maybe hide the entire <div> for IE and Firefox users, and show a different one?

Comment: You could use modernizr to check if clip-path is supported in the browser, then show and hide elements accordingly. However, this still relies on JS.

Comment: One other option that just occurred to me, you could use the `support` API in your CSS. It should work in Firefox but not IE (however it will work in Edge)

Comment: Hmm... What exactly will polyfill do? Do I just have to load the .js file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using JQuery on your site? As that particular polyfill is a JQuery extension

Comment: Yes, I already use a bit of JQuery, but I'm really really new to it. Will everything magicly turn-out alright if I include the clippath.min.js script in the page?

Comment: It appears to be written as a JQuery extension, so make sure you include it after your JQuery script tag. I'm not completely sure if it will as I've never needed to use it, it's just a suggestion to try considering it will only take a minute to do. However, glancing at the code; it appears to be a self-executing closure (unless I'm misunderstanding how jQuery extensions work), so it should just execute automatically